# iOS: How can I get events (with start time > today) from Facebook using FQL?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am trying to write a query in xCode to get my friend's events from FB. The problem is that now it returns me past events as well:

```
@"SELECT name, pic_square, pic, start_time, location, description, pic_cover, venue, eid from event WHERE eid in "
@"(SELECT eid from event_member WHERE uid IN(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()))"
```

After a lot of research I managed to came up with a logical solution, but it doesn't work:

```
NSDate *currDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
NSString *currDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currDate];

NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat: 
@"SELECT name, pic_square, pic, start_time, location, description, pic_cover, venue, eid from event WHERE eid in "
@"(SELECT eid from event_member WHERE uid IN(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())) WHERE start_time > %@" ,currDateString];
```

- I have all the permisions, so that is not the problem.
  Also the start_time returned from the Facebook Graph API is of type NSString (and i am 100% sure that the formatter for the current date is good).

Can somebody please help me figure this out? I am new with FQLs. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't bother specifying the date yourself, get the server to do it by using `start_time > now()`.

Comment: If I am using now() i get this error: Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)

Comment: Have your tokens expired? It used to work and error 5 seems to be an access / auth / permissions type error.

Comment: It can't be that problem because if i am trying the previous version without adding the when start_time > now() it works. I used to get this error also when the query was wrong.

Comment: NSString *query =
    @"SELECT name, pic_square, pic, start_time, location, description, pic_cover, venue, eid from event WHERE eid in "
    @"(SELECT eid from event_member WHERE uid IN(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())) WHERE start_time > now()";

Comment: Looking at the query again, you seem to have to many 'WHERE' clauses. Looks like it should be `AND start_time > now()`.

Answer (score 0):

Facebooks asks for time in epoch format. If you want to fetch any data on the basis of date. You need to send the date in epoch format (UNIX Time Format).

This is how you can get the time which FQL is asking for :

```
[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
```

So the query would be :

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat: 
@"SELECT name, pic_square, pic, start_time, location, description, pic_cover, venue, eid from event WHERE eid in "
@"(SELECT eid from event_member WHERE uid IN(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())) WHERE start_time > %ld" ,[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];
```